# Solve this 'Pigeonhole principle problem' without Pigeonhole principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question goes like this:
Let $A = \{4,5,6,\ldots,61\}$.

We will create set $B$ by randomly choosing $9$ different numbers out of A.
We have to prove that there are at least 2 subset of $B$ that have the same sum of numbers.

The solution is possible using Pigeonhole principle as follows:(you can skip this if you want):

The maximum sum of subset of $B$ (which is not $B$ itself) is $8$ max numbers: $61+60+59+58+57+56+55+54 = 460$. the minimum of is $4$(subset contains this element alone).
So we have $457$ different possibilities for the sum of each subset of $B$.
However, we all know we have that we have $2^9$ different subset of $B$ - and for this specific case we neglect the empty and the complete set, so we have $510$ possibilities for subsets in $B$. because $510 > 457$ and  Pigeonhole principle we are done.

---

All good, but that method appear not to work in other cases, for example if we ask the same question with $A=\{1004,1005,\ldots,1061\}$ - it is easy to see that if it is good for the previous $A$ it should be good also with this $A$. but the method does not work this time.

so I guess there must be another way to solve that question that will be more general.
could you find it ?

Edit: thanks to Thomas, and other comments.. it appears that I missed a thing or two.. so I will change the question is it true at all the the new $A$

Comment: It isn't so easy to see, since two subsets in the first question may have the same sum, but different numbers of elements (e.g. $4+16+25=45$. The sums of the obviously equivalent subsets in the second case will differ by a multiple of $1000$, so the problems are not the same.

Comment: Is it true for that second $A$? It's not obvious it is.

Comment: well, I think...maybe i am wrong....that for every solution of each B i can find the corresponding solution to the second B. simply by adding 1000 to each element

Comment: That's only if the two subsets of $B$ have the same number of elements. Mark's comment. @d_e

Comment: @Thomas, you are right...should I delete the question then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$\begin{align}
B&=1003+\{1,2,4,8,16,32,55,57,58\}\\&=\{1004,1005,1007,1011,1019,1035,1058,1060,1061\}
\end{align}$$

There are no two subsets with the same sum here.